# Zend Framework 1 : Create Model To Access Data From Another Database

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am working on a project (Zend 1.12.3) which is already completed by the previous developer and now I am working on a task to show some information using another database (Not current Database) on a specific section of the webpage.

I just want to know how do I create a model for the table to another database which is not currently in use. All the configuration of current database is in the `application.ini` file.

Should I create a custom query in PHTML file to do this (I know this is a bad coding practice) or is there any other way to show the data from both database?

Thank You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution and it works fine because I need only one model file where I have to access data from another database, Following is my model file i.e **Ticker.php**

### - Ticker.php

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Ticker extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{
    protected $_name = "table_name";
    public  function __construct(){
        $adaptor = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
            'host'     => 'HOST',
            'username' => 'DB_USERNAME',
            'password' => 'DB_PASSWORD',
            'dbname'   => 'DB_NAME'
        ));
        $this->_db = $adaptor;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getTopTickers(){
        try {
            return $this->fetchAll();
        } catch(Exception $e) { die($e->getMessage()); };
    }

}
```